# Getting null in onActivityResult by taking picture from Camera

Tags: android, android-camera, onactivityresult

I created a class to take picture from camera in my application.
This class will take a picture with camera and store it in a folder with an unique name. 
But when I want to get picture path in `onActivityResult` method Iget null of `data` all the time!

this is my class Camera:

```
public class Camera{

  private Activity activity;
  private SystemTools systemTools;


  public Camera(Context context) {

    this.activity = (Activity) context;
    systemTools = new SystemTools();
  }

  /**
   * This Method will take a picture with camera for us
   */

  public void takePicture() {

    boolean cameraAvailable = systemTools.device_isHardwareFeatureAvailable(activity, PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);

    if (cameraAvailable &&
      systemTools.system_isIntentAvailable(activity, MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)) {

      Intent takePicIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

      //We prepare the intent to store the taken picture
      try {

        File outputDir = systemTools.storage_getExternalPublicFolder("ReportsAttachments", true);
        File outFile = systemTools.storage_createUniqueFileName("cameraPic", ".jpg", outputDir);

        takePicIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(outFile));

      } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "در دریافت تصویر اشکالی رخ داده است ، لطفا دوباره تلاش کنید.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      activity.startActivityForResult(takePicIntent, App.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


    } else {
      if (cameraAvailable) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "برنامه ی دوربین دستگاه خراب است.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      } else {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "دسترسی به دوربین سیستم امکان پذیر نمی باشد.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An i Set `onActivityResult()` method in Activity that i used camera. like this:

```
 @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
      if (requestCode == App.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
          Log.i("ATTACH", "In Result");

          Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
          ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

          // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
          Uri selectedImage = getImageUri(this, bmp);
          String realPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
          selectedImage = Uri.parse(realPath);
          presenter.onNewAttachmentRequest(selectedImage.getPath());


        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.i("ATTACH", e + "  Something went wrong");
    }
  }
```

this works fine and taked pictre is avaliable on SD_Card but when I want to get path of picture I cant't because 'data' in `onActivityResult` is null all the time!
Where is the problem with this code?

Thank you.

Comment: make sure you have permissions for storage i.e. read write permissions, if your device is marshmellow or above then please add runtime permissions

Comment: I got all permissions. but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**takePicIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(outFile));**

As you see you have pass the File Uri to the intent i.e the Camera app will write the taken image at this path and will not return the Bitmap.
Just save this path as global in your class and use it in onActivityResult().
You need to add this also cause camera apps are device dependent.

> takePicIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);

Comment: There is no `return-data` extra documented for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: Yeah i know that . It will work without it . I was facing some problem with Moto E camera intent then this is what i have found

Comment: @ADM could you say more about this? I've been having some trouble capturing images on specifically-Motorola devices lately so I'm wondering if this might solve my issue as well.

Comment: @user3678429 Third party stuff does cause problems sometimes thats what i experienced .. I  mostly prefer some picker library which works well in almost all the devices . [here is one](https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage) i have used in past . you can use it on inspect its code to make fixes in yours ..  That's all i can suggest since there has been lots of changes overtime in Storage access framework ..

Answer (score 0):

> when I want to get path of picture

You already have the path of the picture. It is `outFile`. Save it in a field and hold onto it across configuration changes. Also, since `Uri.fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0+ especially well, consider switching to `FileProvider`, as I do in the following activity from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Camera/FileProvider):

```
/***
 Copyright (c) 2008-2017 CommonsWare, LLC
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
 of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
 by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
 OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

 Covered in detail in the book _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
 https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.camcon;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String EXTRA_FILENAME=
    "com.commonsware.android.camcon.EXTRA_FILENAME";
  private static final String FILENAME="CameraContentDemo.jpeg";
  private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
  private static final String AUTHORITY=
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider";
  private static final String PHOTOS="photos";
  private File output=null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
      output=new File(new File(getFilesDir(), PHOTOS), FILENAME);

      if (output.exists()) {
        output.delete();
      }
      else {
        output.getParentFile().mkdirs();
      }

      Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      Uri outputUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, output);

      i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      }
      else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        ClipData clip=
          ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "A photo", outputUri);

        i.setClipData(clip);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      }
      else {
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList=
          getPackageManager()
            .queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
          String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
          grantUriPermission(packageName, outputUri,
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
      }

      try {
        startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
      }
      catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_no_camera, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
      }
    }
    else {
      output=(File)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME, output);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri outputUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, output);

        i.setDataAndType(outputUri, "image/jpeg");
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        try {
          startActivity(i);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
          Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_no_viewer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        finish();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that I have image path but I have it, in Camera class! I want to access it in an Activity that I'm using Camera class.

Comment: @Ehsan: Put a getter on the `Camera` class to return the path. Or have the activity decide the path and pass it to the `Camera` object.